# Depth-to-disparity matrix Q

Tags: python-3.x, camera-calibration, opencv, python

I am using a stereo vision and the command cv2.reprojectImageTo3D() which requires the Q matrix. The Q matrix that I obtained from cv2.stereoRectify() was

```
Q = np.array([[1, 0, 0,  357.10], 
              [0, 1, 0, -138.90], 
              [0, 0, 0,  4775.51], 
              [0, 0, 3.42, 0]])
```

When I try to use cv2.reprojectImageTo3D() with the above Q matrix, I get wrong values. Also, why Q[2,3] is so large? What are the units after applying cv2.reprojectImageTo3D()?

However, many suggest to use

```
h, w = imgL.shape[:2]
f = 0.8 * w 
Q = np.float32([[1,  0, 0, -0.5*w],
                [0, -1, 0,  0.5*h],
                [0,  0, 0, -f],
                [0,  0, 1,  0]])
```

I have the following questions:

1. What is the difference between the two matrices?
2. Is it necessary that the baseline used for calibration and real use must be the same?
3. How to re-scale Q with image resize?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. The matrices are the same, except the suggested Q matrix is an approximation for use in general cases. The `-0.5*w`, `0.5*h` values represent the principal point of the two cameras as if you were to treat them as if they were one unified camera. In your Q matrix obtained from stereoRectify, those same values are roughly the center x,y pixel values of your image. The `f` value is in pixel units, so as long as your calibration was done correctly the large value should be correct.
2. The baselines of calibration and real-use must be identical, these parameters are quite sensitive. Any minor adjustments to the cameras position, skew, etc. require recalibration if you want good results.
3. Generally you should use the same image size during calibration and real-use, but if you want to re-scale you would need to perform calibration with that same image size. You could also try scaling the 357.10 and -138.90 values by the % change from old to new image size.

Overall, it seems you are concerned with the results of `cv.reprojectImageTo3D()`. The units of its output of are somewhat arbitrary in the sense that they are represented in the world-frame coordinate system, where the origin (x,y,z)=(0,0,1) represent the center of the field of view and directly in front of the camera.